# How to respond immediately to a SOAP message in Camel, while invoking other processing?

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel

Basically, I'm looking to respond to a SOAP request immediately, but also kick off further processing. What I'm seeing is that the response is not sent until the route ends. In other words:

```
from("cxf:bean:someEndpoint")
    .to("seda:replySOAP")
    .to("direct:ABCMessage");
from("seda:replySOAP")
    .to("bean:soapReply?method=process").end();
from("direct:ABCMessage")
    .process(new ConvertABCToNZFCY())
    .to("bean:prelimNZFCYCall")
    .end();
```

Does not generate the response until "direct:ABCMessage" has completed. I would think seda would designate asynchronous processing. I have also tried "vm:replySOAP", pointing to a separate Camel Context, and this did not help.

I have also tried multicast, to no avail:

```
from("cxf:bean:someEndpoint")
    .multicast().parallelProcessing()
    .to("seda:replySOAP")
    .to("direct:ABCMessage");
```

What DOES work for me is wireTap, but it does not seem elegant:

```
from("cxf:bean:someEndpoint")
    .wireTap("direct:ABCMessage") 
    .to("direct:replySOAP");
```

Must I use JMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you see is due to

`.to("direct:ABCMessage");`

in the routes. It is a synchronous process ie, an `InOut` exchange pattern. jms can be used but that may be an overkill if you are using it only to avoid wiretap. Why do you think wiretap does not seem elegant.

Comment: The Camel In Action book talks about wiretap in regards to debugging, or on-the-fly message inspection. I would have thought forking an async process would be a fundamental thing in Camel, that I was missing. I suppose wiretap is it! Thanks